# How to update mongodb directly and send data to front-end

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I want to know is there any way to update mongodb document directly in the back end and send updated data to frontend, like how we used to update MySQL dump file and send data to front end.

Comment: Try using findOneAndUpdate() method with option {new: true }. It will return updated document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `findAndUpdate` method using the **mongoTemplate** to update the records and return it in **spring-data-mongodb**, for details please check the official documentation [10.5.6. Finding and Upserting Documents in a Collection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.find-and-upsert). For quick solution, have a look at below code:

```
// find and update and then return
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("firstName").is("First Name"));

Update update = new Update();
update.set("lastName", "modified last name");

FindAndModifyOptions options = new FindAndModifyOptions();
options.upsert(true);
options.returnNew(true);

try {
    Customer modifiedCustomer = mongoOperation
        .findAndModify(query, update, options, Customer.class);
    // Modified data
    System.out.println("Modified Custom data\n");
    System.out.println(modifiedCustomer);
    // Return from here;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}
```

I have commit these code in my github repo, you can look into it: https://github.com/krishnaiitd/learningJava/blob/master/spring-boot-sample-data-mongodb/src/main/java/sample/data/mongo/main/Application.java